# How to Show Other Forms Using DevExpress tileItem in tileControl?

Tags: c#

I am new in C# and DevExpress. I'm trying to show another form by clicking a tile in the tileControl group but it doesn't show up. I just right-clicked at the tileControl, clicked view code and manually declared this since this doesn't automatically shows up if you double click a tile.

```
private void addTile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xForm2 = new XtraForm2();
    xForm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Could you insert a breakpoint at `var xForm2 = new ExtraForm2();`? Does it get hit? If not: Bind your control to the `click_event` if it does: does XtraForm2 exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just right-clicked at the tileControl, clicked view code and manually declared this since this doesn't automatically shows up if you double click a tile.

If I understand this correctly, you did not build your project using the C# code listed above, but only edited the source.

That does not work because what you edit in this way is not being loaded into the app.

Of course, I could be misunderstanding what you wrote.